# Reloading table view yields 0 rows based on "empty" array despite array being appended?

Tags: arrays, swift, tableview

I have a set up where I run a query in the viewDidLoad() of my viewController. The VC contains a `tableView`. The query pulls info from the database and then, once completed, reloads the table view. Here is the general set up:

```
class DetailDisclosureVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    struct Comment {
        var objectID: String
        var userID: String
        var userName: String
        var commentString: String
        var createdAt: Date

        init(objectID: String, userID: String, userName: String, commentString: String, createdAt: Date) {
            self.objectID = objectID
            self.userID = userID
            self.userName = userName
            self.commentString = commentString
            self.createdAt = createdAt
        }

    }

    var orderedComments = [Comment]()

    @IBOutlet weak var commentsTableView: UITableView!

    func query(){
        let commentsQuery = PFQuery(className: "Comments")
        commentsQuery.findObjectsInBackground { (objectss, error) in
            if let objects = objectss{
                print("The objects.count is \(objects.count)") //returns 2
                if objects.count != 0{
                    for object in objects{

                        let individualOrderedComment = Comment(objectID: object.objectId!, userID: object["userID"] as! String, userName: object["userName"] as! String, commentString: object["commentString"] as! String, createdAt: object.createdAt!)

                        self.orderedComments.append(individualOrderedComment)
                    }
                    print(orderedComments.count) //this ALWAYS returns 2, as intended
                    commentsTableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        commentsTableView.dataSource = self
        commentsTableView.delegate = self
        query()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        //number of comments
        print("orderevents count\(orderedComments.count)") //ALWAYS returns 0
        if orderedComments.count != 0{
            return orderedComments.count
            print("Wasnt 0")
        }else{
            return 1
            print("It was 0")
        }
    }

}
```

I know for certain that the query works and that the `orderedComments` array has two values in it. I cannot for the life of me figure out why, even after calling `.reloadData()` at the end of the query, the `numberOfRowsinSection` continues to return a value of 0 for `orderedComments.count` and therefore returns 0 rows. I have played around with adding and removing `self.` to some of the variables, etc... but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: You left out the most important part of your code: the implementation of `query()`.

Comment: @rmaddy I don't understand? I have it at the end of `viewDidLoad()`

Comment: You posted a terribly abbreviated copy of your `query` method. Update your question with the actual, complete implementation of `query`.

Comment: Apart from your issue if you return 1 if the number of items is 0 in `numberOfRowsInSection` your app will crash. You have always to return `orderedComments.count`

Comment: Can you provide which type of  implementation done in `query` function expect reloadData.

Comment: @rmaddy I included the full implementation, please see the updated question

Comment: @vadian I actually left it out but there is a conditional statement for populating the labels based on `orderedComments.count`. If it is 0, I return one cell that just has a label saying "loading comments..." for the time being

Comment: Your update won't even compile. Please post actual code. You append `orderedEventComments` but print `orderedComments`.

Comment: @rmaddy my apologies. It should be good now

Comment: @Smartcat I honestly do not know on which thread it does this, nor how to check.

Comment: You can set a breakpoint on the `reloadData()` line and when it breaks, Xcode will indicate on which thread in the Debug panel, with the call stack.

Answer (score 0):

What thread does findObjectsInBackground() call its completion closure on?  I bet it's not the main thread.  You'd better put the closure's code within a DispatchQueue.main.async like this:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async 
{
   if let objects = objectss
   {
        print("The objects.count is \(objects.count)") //returns 2
        if objects.count != 0
        {
            for object in objects
            {
                let individualOrderedComment = Comment(objectID: object.objectId!, userID: object["userID"] as! String, userName: object["userName"] as! String, commentString: object["commentString"] as! String, createdAt: object.createdAt!)

                self.orderedComments.append(individualOrderedComment)
            }
            print(orderedComments.count) //this ALWAYS returns 2, as intended
            commentsTableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Otherwise your reloadData just won't work (assuming I'm right about the thread it's on.)

Comment: Good thought, but it did not amend the issue

Comment: Any idea why someone downgraded my answer?  I wish the reason for a downgrade could be shown somewhere so I could improve future answers. Oh well.

Comment: Actually @Alek was right about the main thread however you only have put the tableView.reloadData within the main thread closure not the entire completion block. Now if this dosent help you out, you can try calling another method in you viewController from the completionBlock of your query() func updateTableView { tableView.reloadData()}

Comment: @OverD I do not really understand your comment?

Comment: @AlekPiasecki sorry I was trigger happy and posted an incomplete comment...just posted an edit

Comment: @OverD I was trying to avoid Alek having to lock his orderedComments, otherwise it'd be edited on a background thread while at same time possibly read on main thread.  So I'd put the entire closure's code within the dispatch to main - simpler.

Comment: @Smartcat I really do agree with you 100% that its an issue with the the tableView.reload() has to be on the mainThread especially when it's not a tableViewController. but with ur solution the entire query would run on the main thread and not just the tableView.reload.

Comment: @OverD I said to "put the closure's code within this"... in other words, the completion closure to findObjectsInBackground()... so the query isn't on the main thread, just what you do when the query completes.  :)

Comment: I've now edited my answer to be more clear as to what goes in the dispatch to main.